# c# Datagridview (Winform) cell coloring based on adjacent cell value

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Is it possible to color datagridview cell based on multiple conditions.
I know I can change the color of the cells based on that cell value. but is it possible to add condition where i can also apply color based on adjacent cell value.

To compare the cell's date with current date i am using the code below.

```
private void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    if (dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "ACTION PROPOSED DATE")
    {
        if (e.Value == null || e.Value == System.DBNull.Value || e.ColumnIndex < 0 || e.RowIndex < 0)
        {
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            if (((DateTime) e.Value).Date < (DateTime) DateTime.Now.Date)
            {
                e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
                e.CellStyle.ForeColor = Color.White;
            }
        }
    }
    // This section change the color of action proposed description column cell.
    // i want to change the color in "ACTION PROPOSED DATE"column, if "ACTION PROPOSED DESCRIPTION" contains file closed
    else if (dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "ACTION PROPOSED DESCRIPTION")
    {
        if (e.Value == null || e.Value == System.DBNull.Value || e.ColumnIndex < 0 || e.RowIndex < 0)
        {
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            string stringvalue = (string) e.Value;
            stringvalue = stringvalue.ToLower();
            if ((stringvalue.IndexOf("file closed") > -1))
            {
                e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.Purple;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to change the color in the "ACTION PROPOSED DATE" column cell to purple , if "ACTION PROPOSED DESCRIPTION" contains "file closed"

this is the result i get in datagridview

[image: present output]

this is the result i am expecting

[image: expected result]

Before posting I have googled a lot, but I didn't get find any answer to my question. So I hope I didn't repeat this question.

Comment: Kindly format the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The event args of the `CellFormatting` event indicate which cell is **being formatted**. But you can use other cells to determine **how** to format that cell.

For instance, to achieve your goal, you can use something like this:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex < 0 || e.RowIndex < 0) return;
    if (dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "ACTION PROPOSED DATE")
    {
        // Take the other column value for the same row
        var proposedDescription = dg.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["ACTION PROPOSED DESCRIPTION"].Value as string;
        if (proposedDescription != null && proposedDescription.IndexOf("file closed", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0)
        {
             e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.Purple;
             return;
        }
        if (e.Value == null || e.Value == System.DBNull.Value || e.ColumnIndex < 0 || e.RowIndex < 0)
        {
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            if (((DateTime) e.Value).Date < (DateTime) DateTime.Now.Date)
            {
                e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
                e.CellStyle.ForeColor = Color.White;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply change this line of code

```
e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.Purple;
```

to

```
// Note i did change the column name of ACTION PROPOSE DATE
// due to syntax property naming rules.
dataGridView1["ACTION_PROPOSED_DATE", e.RowIndex].Style.BackColor = Color.Purple
```

You have to change this also:

```
else if (dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "ACTION PROPOSED DESCRIPTION")
```

to

```
if (dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "ACTION PROPOSED DESCRIPTION")
```

that your program wont skip on checking your column proposed description.

You can add a condition that will also check if the adjacent cell value is file closed below this line of codes:

```
if (((DateTime) e.Value).Date < (DateTime) DateTime.Now.Date) 
{ 
    e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red; 
    e.CellStyle.ForeColor = Color.White; 
}
```

and make the current cell color to purple. To do that write this code:

```
if (dataGridView1["ACTION_PROPOSED_DESCRIPTION", e.RowIndex].Value.ToString() == "File Closed") 
{ 
    dataGridView1["ACTION_PROPOSED_DATE", e.RowIndex].Style.BackColor = Color.Purple;
}
```

Comment: Your suggestion worked. I am getting expected results without changing the column name also. Thank u for your help. But when the date is less than current date, and the adjacent column is "file closed", the cell gets red color. It has to be purple. can you help me with this?? thank you.

Comment: can you remove the `else` in your else if statement? so the program will continually check the formatted cell value

Comment: hi, i did as you said. still no change..i also change the order, thinking it will work like excel conditional formatting precedence.

Comment: you can add a condition that will also check if the adjacent cell value is `file closed` below this line of codes 

`if (((DateTime) e.Value).Date < (DateTime) DateTime.Now.Date)
            {
                e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
                e.CellStyle.ForeColor = Color.White;
            }`

and make the current cell color to purple.

Comment: I tried for some time, I am unable to solve can u provide me the code,, thank you..

Comment: `if (dataGridView1["ACTION_PROPOSED_DESCRIPTION", e.RowIndex].Value == "File Closed") 
{
     dataGridView1["ACTION_PROPOSED_DATE", e.RowIndex].Style.BackColor = Color.Purple;
}`

please try to put this below the given line of code i mention above.

Comment: Had to add.ToString() after value. I am getting the desired results after following your suggestion thank u very much.  :)

Comment: I think you should update your answer,so that others can find answer for this question, Your real answer is now in the comment section..